# Trying to write a data set from a SQL query out to a CSV file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a CSV file (with no headers if possible) from a SQL query I make.  My powershell is below.  It reads the DB no problem and I see row results come back from printint to stdout.  But I can't seem to figure out how to get the results into a CSV file.

The txt file created from my powershell only has one line it:

## TYPE System.Int32

Which seems to me like it is just outputing the data type or something. It seems odd it is In32 but maybe that is because it is a pointer to the object?

I saw one article that used Tables[0] when using a data set but when I replaced my last line with
$QueryResults.Tables[0] | export-csv c:\tests.txt
It gave me an error saying it couldn't bind an argument to parameter because it was null.

```
function Get-DatabaseData {
param (
    [string]$connectionString,
    [string]$query,
    [switch]$isSQLServer
)
if ($isSQLServer) {
    Write-Verbose 'in SQL Server mode'
    $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
} else {
    Write-Verbose 'in OleDB mode'
    $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
}
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
if ($isSQLServer) {
    $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
} else {
    $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
}
$dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset)
$dataset.Tables[0]
}

$QueryResults = Get-DatabaseData -verbose -connectionString 'Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;;uid=sa; pwd=Mypwd;Database=DanTest;Integrated Security=False;' -isSQLServer -query "SELECT * FROM Computers"
foreach($MyRow in $QueryResults) {
write-output $MyRow.computer
write-output $MyRow.osversion
}

$QueryResults | export-csv c:\tests.txt
```

I added a line to print $QueryResults to stdout and below is the output in the console of that and the write form my for loop to show what my $QueryResults has.

```
5


computer         : localhost
osversion        :
biosserial       :
osarchitecture   :
procarchitecture :

computer         : localhost
osversion        :
biosserial       :
osarchitecture   :
procarchitecture :

computer         : not-online
osversion        :
biosserial       :
osarchitecture   :
procarchitecture :

computer         :
osversion        : win8
biosserial       :
osarchitecture   :
procarchitecture :

computer         : dano
osversion        : win8
biosserial       :
osarchitecture   :
procarchitecture :

localhost

localhost

not-online


win8
dano
win8
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have looping issues as from the sounds of it your `$QueryResults` might not contain the data you are looking for. What does `$QueryResults` look like while in the console? Once you address that this should take care of the output for you.

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

> By default, the first line of the CSV file contains "#TYPE " followed by the fully-qualified name of the type of the object.

To get around that you would just use the `-NoTypeInformation` switch like Alroc suggested. However you also mentioned removing the header which would require a different approach.

```
$QueryResults | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content "c:\tests.txt"
```

or something slightly different with the same result.

```
$QueryResults | ConvertTo-CSV | Select -Skip 2 | Set-Content "c:\tests.txt"
```

Convert the `$QueryResults` to a csv object. However you choose to we omit the lines containing the type information and the header / title row. Should just have nothing but data at that point.

**Update From Discussion**

The `ConvertTo-CSV` and `Export-CSV` were not showing expected data but nothing except type information. I didnt really notice at first but the output of `$QueryResults` contained a first line that was just the number 5. Presumably it was the # of records from the result dataset. If we skip the first record of `$QueryResults` then we are left with just the data needed. Might be better to look into ther reason that first line is there ( maybe there is a way to supress it. ). As the question stands currently we address this as follows. The first skip is to ignore the "5" line and the second is to remove the header from the csv output.

```
$QueryResults | Select -Skip 1 | Convert-ToCSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content "c:\tests.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I added to my original question the output of $QueryResults to Console and the output from my for loop where I print the computer and osversion values.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what should be in the $MyRow values in each loop through the for. I thought it would be each record in the dataset and then I would expect my write-output to print the computer and then osversion for each row. But in the output I get it is printing all three computer values first then all 3 osversions

Comment: I figured out my misunderstanding of $MyRow values.  It looks like it isn't a row I get in the foreach loop but all values in the first column of a dataset.  So I added foreach blocks to print to stdout. e.g. foreach($aRow in $MyRow.computer) { $aRow } gives all the computer names.

Comment: Matt I tried your first suggestion of doing the convert but it doesn't write to a file c:\tests.txt like it did when I had the export-csv call. What my code was writing isn't what I want but the file did exist.

Comment: @user461051 What is the output of `$QueryResults | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation`?

Comment: I added the line $QueryResults | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation into the script and it doesn't print anything to console. But as before if I just do $QueryResults on a line it does print out relevant data to what is in my table like I put in my question above. So it sounds like the conversion isn't producing any output.

Comment: What is the result from this `$QueryResults.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: System.Object[]  I didn't declare $QueryResults to be any particular data type in my code so I assume it gets set to the correct one based on the return object from my Get-DatabaseData call.

Comment: That's odd since it should work. There is something about that data that Export and ConvertTo do not like though.... will have to try and test more.  `$QueryResults` would contain all of the output from your function `Get-DatabaseData`. Does anything odd appear on the console when you run your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66275/discussion-between-user461051-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the data in the CSV file, pass the `-NoTypeInformation` switch into `Export-CSV`.